# What is the best way to create a constant, that can be accessible from entire application in VueJs ?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I can create a constant through a store in my vuejs application, but i don't think it is a good practice.what is other way to do the same?

Comment: if you don't wanna pollute the global scope, you can also use vue instace properties. Check them on the [official docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html) they have some examples and explanation

Answer (score 23):

You can always define a variable outside of the Vue app scope and use it throughout the application.

However, if you are using any bundler like Webpack/Browserify/etc. you can do the same but you'd have to import it into every component using it. An example for that can be found below.

```
//const.js
export default {
   c1: 'Constant 1',
   c2: 'Constant 2'
}

// component.vue
import const from './const';

export default {
  methods: {
    method() {
      return const.c1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the method

```
const State= Object.freeze({ Active: 1, Inactive: 2 });
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      State,
      state: State.Active
    };
  },
  methods: {
    method() {
      return state==State.Active;
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
const State= Object.freeze({ Active: 1, Inactive: 2 });
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      State_: State,
      state: State.Active
    };
  },
  methods: {
    method() {
      return state==State_.Active;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this instead**

```
//conts.js
const test = "texte";

export default test
```

```
//component.vue
import test from "./conts";

<template>
  <div>
   {{example}}
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  data: function(){
   return {
    example: test
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most small big solution

```
//helper.js
    
export const Test = {
  KEY1: 1,
  KEY2: 2,
  KEY3: 3,
  KEY4: 4
}
```

testing the code..

```
//page.vue
import {Test} from "./helper";

<template>
  <div>
   {{testing.KEY2}}
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  data: function(){
   return {
    testing: Test
  }
 }
}
```