# vue.js referencing constants in data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Just wondering, I have the following setup:

```
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      const: {
        monthNames       : ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
      },
      data: {
        year             : (new Date()).getFullYear(),
        month            : (new Date()).getMonth(),
        monthName        : this.monthNames[(new Date()).getMonth()],
        day              : (new Date()).getDate(),
      },
      ...
)}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to pass in `(new Date()).getMonth()` into the `monthNames` array from `const` - but console is returning the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined`.

So my question is simply: *how do I reference monthNames from within data*?

**N.B.** I'm using the most recent js dev build.

Comment: Have you found a solution by yourself or tested any of the answers? Did you find any bugs using them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare it outside the Vue instance or perhaps in another module and import it before using like `import { monthNames } from './constants'`, and then use it whenever you want.

If you want to keep it inside that particular Vue instance then i think it would be better to put it inside the `computed` structure for caching.

Example:

```
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    year             : (new Date()).getFullYear(),
    month            : (new Date()).getMonth(),
    monthName        : monthNames[(new Date()).getMonth()],
    day              : (new Date()).getDate(),
  },
  ...
)
```

A question that matches yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46883212/7395911

A discussion about a constant structure within Vue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6004

Comment: The issue is, when I assign these constants to data and edit from form it gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie to Vue but you can attach it to the Vue simply by calling:

```
Vue.prototype.$monthNames
```

And then calling it within data using `monthNames`

From what I can find you can also use mixins (seems a bit dangerous, affects all components) or simply just declaring a constant before loading the Vue instance.