# How to use enums (or const) in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I feel like an idiot for having to ask about something so seemingly simple, but I'm trying to figure out how to use "enums" in VueJS. Currently, in a file called `LandingPage.js` I have this bit of code:

```js
const Form = {
  LOGIN: 0,
  SIGN_UP: 1,
  FORGOT_PASSWORD: 2,
};

function main() {
  new Vue({
    el: "#landing-page",
    components: {
      LoginForm,
      WhoIsBehindSection,
      WhatIsSection,
      Form,
    },
    data () {
      return {
        form: Form.LOGIN,
      };
    },
    template: `
    <div>
      <LoginForm v-if="form === Form.LOGIN"></LoginForm>
      <WhatIsSection></WhatIsSection>
      <WhoIsBehindSection></WhoIsBehindSection>
    </div>
    `
  });
}
```

It is the conditional `v-if="form === Form.LOGIN"` that is failing with the error messages:

> - Property or method "Form" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
> - Cannot read property 'LOGIN' of undefined

Just so you guys know without the conditional everything is working, and if I were to put this bit in the template

```
<p>{{ form }}</p>
```

it will print `0` on the screen. Though, putting this in the template

```
<p>{{ Form.LOGIN }}</p>
```

Will not result in it printing `0` on the screen. So I just cannot for the life of me figure out why it will not accept `Form.LOGIN`.

**The Answer**

I did add it to `components`, but never did I think of adding it to `data`. Happy that it's working now. :)

```js
    data () {
      return {
        form: Form.LOGIN,
        Form, // I had to add this bit
      };
    },
```

Thank you [MarcRo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11641932/marcro)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You only have access to properties of the Vue instance in your template. Just try accessing `window` or any global in your template, for example.

Hence, you can access `{{ form }}` but not `{{ Form.LOGIN }}`.

A wild guess is that it has something to do with how Vue compiles, but I don't know enough about the internals to answer this.

So just keep declaring all the properties you wish to use in your template in your Vue instance (usually as `data`).

Comment: You can also add Form enum in your Vue instance, outside data function. After, you can access to form enum with $options.Form.LOGIN for example.

Comment: Tbh if it's a constant it's best to declare its as a computed. (computed: someComputed() {return 'abc'}). Data properties are modifiable and they evoke intent of "some method in this components changes this data property", but if you see a computed that immediately returns a const value you know it'll never change at first glance.

Answer (score 39):

If you are using Vue in Typescript, then you can use:

```
import { TernaryStatus } from '../enum/MyEnums';  

export default class MyClass extends Vue {

      myVariable: TernaryStatus = TernaryStatus.Started;

      TernaryStatus: any = TernaryStatus;  

 }
```

and then in Template you can just use

```
<div>Status: {{ myVariable == TernaryStatus.Started ? "Started It" : "Stopped it" }}</div>
```

Comment: No need to use `: any`. `TernaryStatus = TernaryStatus;` works fine.

Comment: how about enum in same file?

Answer (score 29):

You can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/59714524/3706939.

```
const State = Object.freeze({ Active: 1, Inactive: 2 });
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      State,
      state: State.Active
    };
  },
  methods: {
    method() {
      return state === State.Active;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enclose enum into class. All your data, the state, the enum variants would be in one place. The same about behaviours, so you will call `form.isLogin()` rather than `form === Form.LOGIN` and `form.setLogin()` rather than `form = Form.Login`.

The class to generate enums:

```
class Fenum {
  constructor(start, variants) {
    this.state = start;

    variants.forEach(value => {
      const valueC = value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
      this['is' + valueC] = () => this.state === value;
      this['set' + valueC] = () => this.state = value;
    })
  }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
function main() {
  new Vue({
    el: "#landing-page",
    components: {
      LoginForm,
      WhoIsBehindSection,
      WhatIsSection,
      Form,
    },
    data () {
      return {
        form: new Fenum("login", ["login", "signUp", "forgotPassword"]),
      };
    },
    template: `
    <div>
      <LoginForm v-if="form.isLogin()"></LoginForm>
      <WhatIsSection></WhatIsSection>
      <WhoIsBehindSection></WhoIsBehindSection>
    </div>
    `
  });
}
```

Vue observe nested objects, so each call of a set method (`from.setLogin()`, `form.setSignUp()`, ...) will trigger updates of the component as it should be.

The generated object from this example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use $options instead of $data `https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options`

Answer (score 2):

For 2022 and beyond you should probably be using **Vue 3** and Typescript.

The easiest way to use an enum is to map it to string values and then simply return it from your setup function.

```
<template>
  ...
  <div v-if="mode == DarkModes.DARK">
    do something for dark mode
  </div>
  ...
</template>

<script lang="ts">

enum DarkModes {
  BRIGHT = 'bright',
  DARK = 'dark',
}

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyDarkOrBrightComponent',
  setup() {
    const mode = ref(DarkModes.BRIGHT);
    ...
    return {
      mode,
      DarkModes, // <- PASS YOUR ENUM HERE!
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

And if you're using the new `<script setup>` functionality it's just as easy ... all top level imports are automatically accessible from the template (if you want to put your enum in a separate file).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Proxy` to create object which throw runtime errors if someone will read non-defined value or try to add new value - here is `createEnum` (and use it in `data()` section)

```js
function createEnum(name,obj) {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, property) {
        if (property in target) return target[property];
        throw new Error(`ENUM: ${name}.${property} is not defined`);
    },
    set: (target, fieldName, value) => {
      throw new Error(`ENUM: adding new member '${fieldName}' to Enum '${name}' is not allowed.`);
    }
  });
}
  

// ---------------
// ----- TEST ----
// ---------------

const Form = createEnum('Form',{
  LOGIN: 0,
  SIGN_UP: 1,
  FORGOT_PASSWORD: 2,
});

// enum value exists
console.log(Form.LOGIN);

// enum value not exists
try{ console.log(Form.LOGOUT) } catch(e){ console.log(e.message)}

// try to add new value
try{ Form.EXIT = 5 } catch(e){ console.log(e.message)}
```

for string-like Enums where values are equal to keys you can use following helper

```js
export function createEnumArr(name='', values=[]) {
  let obj = {};
  values.forEach(v => obj[v]=v);
  return createEnum(name,obj);
}

const Form = createEnumArr('Form',[
      "LOGIN",
      "SIGN_UP",
      "FORGOT_PASSWORD",
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way!

in main.js

```
const enumInfo = {
  SOURCE_TYPE: {
    WALLET: 1,
    QR: 2
  }
}

Vue.prototype.enumInfo = enumInfo
```

index.vue

```
{{enumInfo}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've this problem, too.

Here my solution, just put this in the first line:

```
<script setup>
const Form = {
  LOGIN: 0,
  SIGN_UP: 1,
  FORGOT_PASSWORD: 2,
};
</script>
```