# Enums in Vue and javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, enums

I want to make enums work in  in vue file.

I first define my enums in a js file

```
const Status= Object.freeze({
    Normal: "normal",
    Loading: "loading",
    Error: "error",
    Done: "done",
});

export default Status;
```

My main.vue file can't compile:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="status == AudioCardStatus.Normal">
</template>

import Status from "./../enums/status"
```

Error is

> Property or method "Status" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

I have already looked at another similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57538539/how-to-use-enums-or-const-in-vuejs) but the solution seems to be to use Typescript.

Comment: which vue version are you using?

Comment: All JS should be located in script tag. Is this your exact code in  main.vue ? If it's not then there's a problem with the question. "the solution seems to be to use Typescript" - answers aren't limited to the first post, you can read them all. Enums are TS constructs, that's why TS appeared in search results. It doesn't matter what's the role of the constant is and whether you use Object.freeze, it's treated the same way in your case, this is basically a var from another module

Answer (score 3):

You should add that imported object to the data option in order to be available for the template :

```
import Status from "./../enums/status"

export default{
   data(){
     return{
        status:Status
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You import it as `Status` but use it as `AudioCardStatus`, Also you need to asign it to property in your `data`.

Second, you should import it inside a `script` tag.

Third, you don't need the extra `./` this enough `../enums/status`